# id dinamico para autorización o descarte de propuestas

Tags: javascript, php

estoy elaborando un sistema en el cual se deban autorizar o rechazar las propuestas, el detalle es que al momento de darle en autorizar, me sale el mensaje de alerta y al presionar aceptar, no me deshabilita los botones ni pinta de verde la fila de la propuesta que se esta autorizando o rechazando. El código es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
        $servername = "";
        $database = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";

        $connection = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM propuestas";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connection,$consulta);
        ?>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $row['numero']?>">
            <td> <?php echo $row['motivo']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['rpe_titular']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['nombre_titular']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['categoria_titular']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['plaza']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['rpe_suplente']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['nombre_suplente']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['periodo_inicial']?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['periodo_final']?></td>
            <td id="status"> 
                <button class="BtnStatus" title="aprobar" id="aprobar" name="aprobar" value="<?php echo $row['numero']?>" onclick="aprobar(this)">Aprobar</button>
                <button class="BtnStatus" title="rechazar" id="rechazar" name="rechazar" value="<?php echo $row['numero']?>" onclick="rechazar()">Rechazar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        } mysqli_close($connection);
        ?>
        <tr>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function aprobar(valor){
        var id = $(valor).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    }
       function aprobar(valor){
        var opcion = confirm("¿Está seguro de aprobar la propuesta?");
        if(opcion==true)
        {
            document.getElementById(valor).style.backgroundColor = "green";
            document.getElementById('aprobar').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('rechazar').disabled = true;
        }
       }
```

[image: Vista de la tabla]

Comment: estas repitiendo ids `id="status"` por ejemplo, a cada boton ponele solamente una class y un `data-deleteid=`/`data-rejectid=` con el id del row, lo usas luego con `btn.getAttribute('data-deleteid')` o simplemente un `data-rowid`

Comment: Entendí lo primero, ya le quité el id status, pero tengo un poco de confusión con lo que mencionaste después, me podrías decir como quedaría entonces esa línea de código? gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué defines dos veces `function aprobar(valor)`? El id que quieres modificar es del `<tr>` padre del `<td>` padre del `<button>`presionado?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estaba viendo de que manera me podía servir la función, pero olvidé comentar una de ellas, y si, se trata de que ese tr cambie a verde si se autoriza, o en su defecto a rojo si se rechaza